# Evaluating $\int \sqrt{x^2 + 2x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \sqrt{x^2 + 2x}dx$$

I have no clue what to do on this problem. It is in the trig substitution chapter so I know I have to use that somehow. I know that I can not complete the square because both terms are positive and will not give me a difference of squares.

I know u subsitution will not work because I get leftover x terms.

I know that I basically have to manipulate this problem algebraically before I can work with it but I just do not know how to do that.

I tried to factor out an x or -x but neither makes progress.

Comment: Complete the square: $x^2+2x=(x+1)^2-1$.

Comment: @Jordan: Since you have asked quite a few question last days, I wanted to make sure that you're aware of 50 questions/month limit, see meta: [How much asking is too much?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/how-much-asking-is-too-much) I thought this information might be useful for you.

Comment: So it seems that I was wrong about the limit on the number of questions per month, see here: [Have the limits on number of questions per month/day been increased (or cancelled)?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same thing as the last one. Use
$$
\int \sqrt{x^2 + 2x }\ \ dx = \int \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 1 - 1}\ \  dx = \int \sqrt{(x + 1)^2 - 1}\ \  dx
$$
and use the hint $\sec \theta = x+1$.

Comment: I think I have been doing math for too long today, this was really obvious and I spent about 20 minutes just trying to complete the square.

Comment: @Jordan You're definitely improving. Keep it up.

Comment: $dx$'s tsk tsk.

Answer (score 4):

Ok. Here is a general method of solving integrals of the form $P(x) = ax^{2}+bx+c$.

\begin{align*}
ax^{2}+bx+c &= a \cdot(x^{2}+\frac{b}{a} x) + c \\\ &= a \cdot \biggl(x^{2}+ \frac{b}{a} \cdot x  +\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\biggr) + c - \frac{b^2}{4a} \\\ &= a \cdot \biggl(x+\frac{b}{2a}\biggr)^{2} + c-\frac{b^2}{4a}
\end{align*}

Now after doing this put $\displaystyle x+\frac{b}{2a} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \cdot \sqrt{\biggl(c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\biggr)} \cdot \tan\theta$

Comment: Nice answer chandu +1.